# How to use svg image clickable areas and close button with jquery to show and hide divs, with only one div visible at a time

Tags: html, jquery, css

The code below allows an area on an image to be highlighted by hovering over it and when that area is clicked on opens a corresponding div. When the area is clicked on again the div will be closed. Also there is a close button inside the div which will close the div when clicked on. All this is working but I would like only one div to be open at a time, so when another area is clicked on, when that div opens the other div will close automatically if the close button has not been used to close it. In this example there are only two clickable areas, green squares and two corresponding divs but the real application will have over twenty clickable areas with corresponding divs so I need a solution that is efficient and scalable.
I am very new to jquery and I have spent a few days looking for a solution so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here is a link to working code so far [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/atataylor/r7L0wepv/)

```js
$('.area1, .btn').click(function() {
  $('.info1').toggle(1000);

});

$('.area2, .btn2').click(function() {
  $('.info2').toggle(1000);

});
```

```css
#boxes {
  width: 400px;
}

.info1,
.info2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  display: none;
}

.area1,
.area2 {
  fill: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.area1:hover,
.area2:hover {
  fill: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.btn,
.btn2 {
  float: right;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

.btn:before,
.btn2:before {
  content: "\2715";
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<center>
  <svg id="boxes" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 392 344">
            <g>
              <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="391" height="343" fill="#fff"/>
              <path d="M743,158V500H353V158H743m1-1H352V501H744V157Z" transform="translate(-352 -157)"/>
            </g>
            <g id="box2">
                <title>Click her for box 2 info</title>
              <rect class="area2" x="197.5" y="172.5" width="194" height="171" fill="#d1cbcb"  />
              <path  d="M743,330V500H550V330H743m1-1H549V501H744V329Z" transform="translate(-352 -157)"/>
            </g>
            <g id="box1" >
                <title>Click her for box 1 info</title>
              <rect  class="area1" x="0.5" y="0.5" width="194" height="171" fill="#d1cbcb"/>
              <path   d="M546,158V328H353V158H546m1-1H352V329H547V157Z" transform="translate(-352 -157)"/>
            </g>
          </svg>

  <div class="info1 ">Info box 1
    <button class="btn"></button>
  </div>
  <div class="info2">Info Box 2
    <button class="btn2"></button>
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: have you considered using a non-script solution by using `anchors` + `:target` to show and hide elements?

Comment: @tacoshy, thanks  tacoshy for your comments, I haven't , I will look into it as I am always interested in learning new ways of doing things. However I would also like to learn the most efficient jquery way of doing this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far i understood, you want to be able to close by the X button, and also if you click another div, to open right message and close the other.

If that is right, you will need the [.hide() function of jquery](https://api.jquery.com/hide/).

Here is the jquery code you will need to add (I tried on your jsfiddle demo):

Option 1.

```
$('.area1, .btn').click(function(){
           $('.info1').toggle(1000);
          $('.info2').hide(1000);
       });
       
       $('.area2, .btn2').click(function(){
           $('.info2').toggle(1000);
          $('.info1').hide(1000);
       });
```

Option 2.

```
$('.area1, .btn').click(function(){
  var $this = $('.info1').toggle(1000);
  $('*[class^="info"]').not($this).hide(1000);
});

$('.area2, .btn2').click(function(){
  var $this = $('.info2').toggle(1000);
  $('*[class^="info"]').not($this).hide(1000);
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer very simple and works but, is there away to do it in a scalable way, as this would get very complex with lost of divs.

Comment: I will edit and add a second option more scalable. let me know if you like the solution

Comment: thanks Skatt works brilliantly exactly what I was looking for. I will need to look into it further to understand how it works( *[class^="info"]). So you have helped me to learn as well thanks again.